# How can I define a chapter into this document? (article)

Tags: chapters, article

Skeleton:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\chapter{How can I make this be understood correctly?} 

\section{This, instead, works}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `article` doesn't have a `\chapter` command (articles in general don't usually have chapters). use `book` or `report` instead: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}`.

Comment: I'd like to, but I even need the \abstract structure to work! :( can I achieve both of them? @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: `report` has the same `abstract` environment that `article` has, so it should do what you want.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Or use `memoir` it's like `book` but also have the `abstract` env